# Rails - preprocessing in DB layer (PG)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

Given that I use Postgres and have this method:

```
  def undelivered_messages(datetime)
    messages = {}
    @current_user.conversations.includes(:user_messages).each do |c|
      messages[c.id] = c.user_messages.where('user_id != ? AND created_at > ?', @current_user.id, datetime)
    end
    JSON.generate(messages)
  end
```

I expect this output to look like (not counting JSON.generate()):

```
{1=>[m1,m2,m3], 2=>[m1,m2,m3]}
```

I wonder, can I do this thing by some SQL query at DB level, so DB prepares hash (or JSON object), which would like to be faster, as Ruby is slow, and databases are not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
UserMessage
 .joins(:conversation)
 .where('user_messages.user_id != ? AND user_messages.created_at > ?', @current_user.id, datetime)
 .where(conversations: { user_id: @current_user.id })
 .group_by(&:conversation_id)
```

Comment: `group_by` is ruby method, so it will group messages in ruby. My point was if it is possible at DB layer. pg  `array_agg` seems something close but I'm not sure

Comment: don't know either, I use to make this kind of call if I want to group records by  an id... the advantage here is that you're retrieving the stuff you need with a single query, instead of quering user's conversations and then user messages in order to build that hash... maybe that's why it's a little bit slow. I'll pay attention to this thread if someone knows a proper answer, that would be cool (cos, you're saving that extra `group_by`)

Comment: If you're just trying to group, then yes, you could use array_agg to build a Postgres array for each ID. Something like SELECT array_agg(user_id) FROM ... GROUP BY conversation_id. Note that if you have many conversations or conversations with a lot of users you'll probably still be unhappy with the quantity of data you just asked ruby to handle (and then GC).

Comment: https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/05/27/avoid-rails-when-generating-json-responses-with-postgresql ultra-fancy, now I need to figure out how I imply this in my case